# Link to user who created this post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the models `Forum`, `Topic` and `Post`, and I need to create a link to the user who created this post. This is my example:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
    tr
        td | user
        td = post.content
        td = post.created_at
        td = link_to post.user.login, user_path(@user)
```

Topics controller:

```
def show
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topics = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @topics.posts
  @user = @topics.user
```

All my relations seem to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, partly due to variable names, and partly because you don't actually say what the problem is.   But i think that you should be able to say

```
 td = link_to post.user.login, user_path(post.user)
```

What i meant about variable names is that sometimes you use the plural form to refer to single objects, for example i would rewrite your show action as

```
def show
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @topic.posts
end
```

and then in the view do

```
    - @posts.each do |post|
      tr
        td | user
        td = post.content
        td = post.created_at
        td = link_to post.user.login, user_path(post.user)
```

Comment: I dont understand why when i must create link_to find user who created Topic. i Use
td = link_to @user.login, user_path(@user) 
and when i want to find user who create post i must write
   td = link_to post.user.login, user_path(post.user)   

Trouble in this  user_path(@user)  AND    user_path(post.user)

Comment: In your question you say "I need to create a link to the user who created this post".  Do you actually want to link to the user who created the topic?  If so then please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
td = link_to post.user.login, user_path(post.user)
```